# check cookie - if found display link

Tags: php, html, cookies, session-cookies

I want to display a link to a user when he has an cookie named abc in his browser

```
<?php
$cookie = abc;
if (!$cookie)
{
  echo <br><center><a href="http://om-p.com/" target="_blank">click here</a></center></b>;
}
?>
```

how could I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The PHP global `$_COOKIE` could be used to check the user's cookies

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["abc"]))
{
  echo '<br><center><a href="http://om-p.com/" target="_blank">click here</a></center></b>';
}
?>
```

check http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if it is set in the $_COOKIE variable:

```
<?php
$cookie = abc;
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie])) 
{
  echo <br><center><a href="http://om-p.com/" target="_blank">click here</a></center></b>;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

study the php tag $_COOKIE on php.net
and add the "" into the right places.... like: echo "...